# Caesar Shift Problems

Tags: c++, arrays, caesar-cipher

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int randchar(void)
{//rand char generation
int c = ' ';

    while (!isalpha(c))

        {
        c = rand() * 1010110;
        c %= 26;
        c += 'a';
        c %= 'z';
        }

    return c;

}//end randchar

int main(int argc, char * argv[], char **env)
{//array input and processing
char c;
string s;

c = cin.get();

while (!cin.eof())
{//run until end of message

    if(isalpha(c))
        s = s + c;

    c = cin.get();

    //cout <<"s is: " << s.length() <<"\n";

    int length = s.length(), side=1, count=0, row, col;


    while((side * side) < length) //start matrix as one by one increase until string length = width/length of array sides
            side++;

     char matrix[side][side];//create char matrix [side][side]


    for(row=0; row < side; row++) //increase rows until same size as side
    {

        for (col=0; col < side; col++)//increase cols until same size as side
        {

            if (count < length)//if count is less than string length

                {
                matrix[row][col] = s[count++];//fill matrix[row][column] using string s until count = string length
                }

            else

                {
                matrix[row][col] = randchar(); //if count >= string length, fill remaining space with rand characters
                count++;
                }//else end

        }//for ends

    }//for ends
    for (col=0; col < side; col++)

    {

      for (row=0; row < side; row++)

        cout << matrix[row][col]; //prints out final encrypted array

    }//for ends
}//while end

}//end main
```

So I'm having problems identifying why this code prints out every array from 1 x 1 to s.length() x s.length() instead of only printing the final encrypted array. abcdefghi should print out adgbehcfi, but it prints aaIboacbgacbdadIbeWcSMadMbeecfkadgbemcfQadgbehcfc**adgbehcfi** and after pressing enter, **adgbehcfi**.

I'm thinking that I need to print out the array after the while loop ends or am I missing something else here? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have your print loop inside your encrypt loop.  Some proper indentation would show that quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

You did a nested for loop that loop all the rows and all the columns of the `matrix` array, and put the print statement `cout << matrix[row][col];` inside this nested loop. So it will be executed for each row and each column. To solve this you can remove the for loops, replacing this:

```
for (col=0; col < side; col++)
{
    for (row=0; row < side; row++)
        cout << matrix[row][col]; //prints out final encrypted array
}//for ends
```

by this:

```
cout << matrix[side-1][side-1]; //prints out final encrypted array
```